# How could a nautilus work together with a man o' war?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, sea-creatures

There are two animals in symbiosis

One of these animals is a type of nautilus. It is small, at around 10cm long, and has a smaller phragmacone. They have long, strong cirri, which they use to hold on to their host. They have a better-developed hyponome, which they use to drag along their host. Multiple nautili live on each host, with around 6 adults usually

The other animal, the host, is similar to a man o' war. It is larger, about 1m long. In addition to the usual organs that a man o' war has, it bears 6 stiff outward-pointing structures that the nautili can hold onto

How could these organisms and their relationship evolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/drag along their host/

You gave up your concept!  Which I will flesh out.

The hydrozoan has an inflatable sail and without its commensals, is at the mercy of the winds.  It cannot move towards prey and it is at real risk of being beached and dying in the sun.

The nautili are motile in a way the colonial hydrozoan is not.  The nautili can swim towards prey or away from predators - or the beach.  Having the nautili attached confers motility otherwise lacking; without the nautili the hydrozoan moves only a little and mostly drifts.

The nautili benefit from the protection of the man-o-war tentacles, which do not sting them because the nautili are covered with the same mucus as the hydrozoan which recognizes them as "self".  Predators which might eat the nautili do not want to get mixed up with the hydrozoan and stung.  Nautili claim some prey caught by the hydrozoan.  The nautili might also snack on hydrozoan tentacles - only worn out or tangled ones, of course.